# How to do with creating a count of types in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a array now want to count of type in an array.

My code:

```js
arr = [function() {}, new Object(), [], {}, NaN, Infinity, undefined, null, 0];

console.log({...arr});
```

but I want result like given  below format, how can I achieve that?

```
OutPut: { function: 1, object: 4, number: 3, undefined: 1 }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: The title and question don't really seem to match the input/output you are describing. What does "ordering" have to do with creating a count of types in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the types.

```js
const
    array = [function() {}, new Object(), [], {}, NaN, Infinity, undefined, null, 0],
    result = array.reduce((r, v) => {
        const type = typeof v;
        r[type] = (r[type] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `??` is faster than `||`

Comment: @TachibanaShin, is speed really the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to get the `typeof` each of the entries and sum it up in an object.

Here is an example:

```js
const arr = [function() {}, new Object(), [], {}, NaN, Infinity, undefined, null, 0];

const obj = arr.map(e => typeof e).reduce((o,t) => ({...o, [t]: (o[t] ?? 0) + 1 }), {})
console.log(obj);
```